# b2Body questions

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have 2 questions with b2Body:

1. What is the difference between b2Body and b2BodyDef?
2. How would I add a b2Body to a CCScene with coordinates from a CGRect which I already have coded? Also how would I add userData to it so I can keep a reference to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `b2BodyDef` is used to *define* information about a body as a whole, such as position and rotation. Compared to the other information you require for a `b2Body`, such as *friction* and *resititution*, that is defined on a per fixture basis using `b2Fixtures`. The `b2Body` is an amalgamation of a body definition and at least one fixture.

With regard to creating the body from a predefined rect, I'd advise using `setAsBox:` assuming you are using a `b2PolygonShape`.

The way I usually accomplish the joining of the two is to create a class called `BodyNode` which has ivars of a `b2Body` and a `CCSprite`. Assign either the `BodyNode`, i.e. `self` or the sprite as the `userData` and update them as follows:

```
-(void) onEnter
{
    [self scheduleUpdate];
    [super onEnter];
}

-(void) update:(ccTime) dt
{
    //Update the position of the sprite to the position of the body
    //Update the rotation of the body to the rotation of the sprite. Take care to note that the rotation of the sprite is in degrees whereas the rotation of the body is in radians.
}
```